# Problem with [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'

Tags: json, api, flutter, dart, mobile

**I am trying to get data from an json file from an API**

Here is my code for deserialize:

```
import 'package:curso_project/Classes/listaTokenLoja.dart';

class LoginInfo {
  String resp;
  int idLogin;
  List<ListaTokenLoja> listaTokenLoja;

  LoginInfo(this.resp, this.idLogin, [this.listaTokenLoja]);

  factory LoginInfo.fromJson(dynamic json) {
    if (json['lista_toquem_loja'] != null) {
      var listaTokenObjJson = json['lista_toquem_loja'] as List;
      List<ListaTokenLoja> _listaToken = listaTokenObjJson
          .map((listaJson) => ListaTokenLoja.fromJson(listaJson))
          .toList();
      return LoginInfo(
          json['resp'] as String, json['id_login'] as int, _listaToken);
    } else {
      return LoginInfo(json['resp'] as String, json['id_login'] as int);
    }
  }

  @override
  String toString() {
    return '{${this.resp}, ${this.idLogin}, ${this.listaTokenLoja}}';
  }
}
```

Here is my call API func:

```
postRequest(login, psd) async {
  final http.Response response = await http.post(
    'http://pdvapi.salaomaster.com.br/logarcli',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
    },
    body: jsonEncode({"login": login, "pw": psd, "json_xml": "json"}),
  );
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    var json2 = response.body;
    LoginInfo loginInfo = LoginInfo.fromJson(jsonDecode(json2));
    print(loginInfo.idLogin);
    var json = response.body.toString();
    var responseSliced = checkLogin(json);

    return responseSliced;
  } else {
    print(response.statusCode);
    throw Exception('Erro: ${response.statusCode}');
  }
}
```

Here is the error:

```
I/flutter ( 2696): postando...
I/flutter ( 2696): 1
I/flutter ( 2696): k7f32Sa#
E/flutter ( 2696): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'
E/flutter ( 2696): #0      new LoginInfo.fromJson
package:curso_project/Classes/loginInfo.dart:13
E/flutter ( 2696): #1      postRequest
package:curso_project/api/login.dart:21
E/flutter ( 2696): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 2696): #2      LoginPage.build.<anonymous closure>
package:curso_project/main.dart:132
E/flutter ( 2696): #3      _InkResponseState._handleTap
package:flutter/…/material/ink_well.dart:993
E/flutter ( 2696): #4      _InkResponseState.build.<anonymous closure>
package:flutter/…/material/ink_well.dart:1111
```

I cant find where is the problem, because its indicating  a line where is a List not a String
I am new to flutter and dart, i have been developing some apps with them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was changing the way that json comes, it was coming like an String , so I used  the jsonDecode(), it solved the problem